# What do protofiles represent for googles API Linter?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, google-api-linter

since google did not create extensive documentation for their API Linter and I cannot find anything from other sources, i wanted to ask here.

**From what exactly am i supposed to create protofiles and what do they represent?**
As I understood, these protofiles get checked for compliance to their AIPs.

I'm interested in creating a automatic prototype (Java) to check for customized API Rules and am thinking about using Protobufer for this goal. Would this be a pragmatic solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Proto files are the source of truth for the API definition. The programmer writes the proto files directly; language-specific code is generated from them.

Answer (score 0):

As I now understand, Googles API Linter isn't supposed to check a API or a different API specification for compliance.

It checks proto files because they are themself the API specification and can be converted to Code. But before converting them they can be checked against rules they have to comply with.
These rules are not in the protofiles (as I initially thought) but in the many GO-files under rules/ .

Please correct me if you read this and find mistakes! Thanks!